# .NET Core - Create Custom AuthorizationAttribute With Parameter

Tags: c#, .net-core, parameters, authorize-attribute

nI have a requirement to validate that an incoming request from a partner (say contoso.com) truly originated from the partner using Forward-Confirmed Reverse DNS (FCrDNS).

The process consists of 5 steps at a high-level:

1. Determine the remote IP of the request
2. Perform a DNS lookup on that IP to get the host name for the IP
3. Verify the host name contains the domain name of the partner (contoso.com)
4. Do a DNS lookup on the host name from step #2
5. Verify that the list of IP addresses from the DNS lookup contains the original remote IP from step #1

My intention was to create a custom AuthorizeAttribute for this function. But since the function isn't specific to the partner contoso.com, I don't want to hard-code that domain in my AuthorizeAttribute.

I would like to be able to parameterize that value with the attribute so it could be used like so:

```
[Route("contoso/subscriber")]
[Authorize(AuthorizationSchemes = AuthTypes.FCrDNS, "contoso.com")]
public async Task<ActionResult> PostSubscriber()
{
    ...
}
```

But I haven't been able to find a way to do this.

I found articles that said I could add another parameter to my attribute's constructor, but it doesn't seem to work (maybe it's an MVC vs Core thing)

---

**CLARIFICATION:** The authorization code that I created to perform the forward and reverse DNS lookups does work if I hard-code the domain name I wish to compare in my `CheckAuthentication()` method (which I have omitted here). What is *not* working is even though I included the additional parameter in the attribute constructor to attempt to pass in the domain name string as parameter does not make the parameter available on the attribute when I decorate my endpoint with it. That is:

[Authorize(AuthorizationSchemes = AuthTypes.FCrDNS, **"contoso.com"**)]

Thanks @John Wu

---

https://vivien-chevallier.com/Articles/create-a-custom-authorizeattribute-that-accepts-parameters-of-type-enum

```
    public class FCrDNSAuthenticationSchemeOptions : AuthenticationSchemeOptions
    { }

    public class FCrDNSAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<FCrDNSAuthenticationSchemeOptions>
    {
        private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        private DBContext db;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        private readonly Common.UserSettings.Settings _systemParameters;
        private readonly string _forHost;

        public FCrDNSAuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<FCrDNSAuthenticationSchemeOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock, DBContext dbContext, AppSettings settings, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, Common.UserSettings.Settings systemParameters, 
            params string[] ForHost) // <-------------------------
            : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
        {
            db = dbContext;
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            _systemParameters = systemParameters;
            _forHost = ForHost[0];
        }

        protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
        {
            const string METHOD_NAME = "FCrDNSAuthenticationHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync";
            logger.Trace($"{METHOD_NAME}: Start");

            // Validate the authentication
            if (!CheckAuthentication()) // Guts of the DNS checks.
            {
                logger.Error($"{METHOD_NAME}: Authentication Failed");
                return AuthenticateResult.Fail(LocalizationAPIMessage.AUTHENTICATION_FAILED.GetTranslation());
            }

            logger.Info($"{METHOD_NAME}: Authentication Successful");

            logger.Trace($"{METHOD_NAME}: Stop");
            return await API.AuthenticationUser.Set(db, null, _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext, this.Scheme.Name, Request.Query["ldfmt"].FirstOrDefault(), _systemParameters);
        }
```

To be honest, I'm not sure if this should be a scheme, policy, or role (prob. not a role). But I was following the scheme pattern because that seems to be our pattern.

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work." Can't really help without a more specific description. Also, can't tell you what's wrong with your attribute code unless you include it. Feel free to edit your post to include more information.

Comment: I think a policy makes more sense than a scheme. Have a look at [the documentation on custom AuthorizationPolicy providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-5.0) - they show an example of using custom attributes, which seems like what you need

Comment: Which method you use depends on how you wish to use it. Do you want to perform this test at login? On every request? Where are you going to cache the result?

Comment: Bear in mind that (in theory) a user could login from a phone/laptop on site wifi, then go to a coffee shop...